# Benchmark machine-learning model in MLR3 with randomized data

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, mlr

I am conducting machine-learning in R using mlr3. I would like to assess the performance of my model by conducting a benchmark of my model using real and also randomized data.
Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)

# generate task data and randomized data
df <- palmerpenguins::penguins 
df_randomized <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(), sample)) 
task = TaskClassif$new("penguings", df, target = "species")
task_randomized = TaskClassif$new("penguings", df_randomized, target = "species")

# prepare learner
lrn_rpart = lrn("classif.rpart")
cv3 = rsmp("cv", folds = 3)

# running analysis
rr = resample(task, lrn_rpart, cv3)
rr_randomized = resample(task_randomized, lrn_rpart, cv3)

rr$aggregate(msr("classif.ce"))
rr_randomized$aggregate(msr("classif.ce"))
```

My analysis is much more complex than this example (hyperparameter tuning, repeated nested cross-validation) so that this analysis quickly becomes very time-consuming.

Therefore, my question would be:

- Is there any implemented functions to conduct such "randomized-data" benchmarks?
- Is it recommended to shuffle the target column, the predictor columns or both?
- Is it sufficient to shuffle once and then run the analysis or would you recommend to shuffle/analyse multiple times (e.g. to generate a distribution of model performances given randomized data).
- If yes are there any recommendations how many iterations of randomize/analyse should be conducted?

---

EDIT

Thanks to your helpful comments, I could re-write the code to use mlr3benchmark with two tasks (one original task, one task with randomized data). This is much more compact.

Regarding your questions:
I am mainly interested in quantifying potential overfitting of my model ("how much better the model is compared to a model based on just random data...").

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3benchmark)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(dplyr)

df <- palmerpenguins::penguins 
df_randomized <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(), sample)) 
task = TaskClassif$new("penguings", df, target = "species")
task_randomized = TaskClassif$new("penguings", df_randomized, target = "species")

# create list of just one learner
learners = list(lrn("classif.rpart"))

design = benchmark_grid(
  c(task, task_randomized),
  learners, 
  rsmp("cv", folds = 3))

bmr = benchmark(design)
bmr$aggregate(msr("classif.acc"))[, .(task_id, learner_id, classif.acc)]
```

But I am wondering: instead of creating two different tasks, would it be better to create two different models (e.g. one normal model and one model that has a preprocessing operator with colapply to shuffle all predictor colums)? This would assure that I have the same CV-folds for both tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a partial answer. Each of my bullet points is intended as an answer to your four bullet points.

- At least within `mlr3`, there is no such functionality, but it is also not really necessary as this is really easy to implement as you show yourself. Note that the mlr3 book has a chapter dedicated to larg(er) benchmark experiments (https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/chapters/chapter11/large-scale_benchmarking.html). In case you have access to a high performance computing cluster, this will also teach you tools how to conduct such experiments more easily.
- This depends on what your goal is, what is you goal? Considering you are shuffling your data randomly, are you interested in investigating overfitting behaviour of your algorithm? But also, see the two points below
- This depends on the variance of your analysis and how certain you want to be in your analysis. You should get an idea, how much the specific shuffling influences the result.
- This also depends on the variance of your results.

As some follow up questions: Are you only interested in one specific dataset or in the behaviour of the algorithm in general? In the latter case, I would strongly recommend looking at more than one dataset. The R package `mlr3oml` (that is also shown in the chapter I mentioned above), shows you how easily obtain benchmark datasets from OpenML.